# Upgrading hibernate version to 5.4 gives me 'no transaction is in progress'

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, upgrade, hibernate-5.x

I am trying to upgrade spring version(4.3) and hibernate version(5.4) and I am getting 'no transaction is in progress' exception, I am using HibernateTransactionManager and also I have tried with  setting hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class to 'jta' as well as 'jdbc'. my configs are below

```
<bean id="MyTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="myAppSessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

<bean id="myAppSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>            
               <value>classpath:/mappings/UserGroupMembershipPOJO.hbm.xml</value>               
                <value>classpath:/mappings/UserGroupPOJO.hbm.xml</value>
                 <value>classpath:/mappings/UserDetailsPOJO.hbm.xml</value>                      
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
               
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="myDataSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Hibernate now conforms with the JPA specification to not allow flushing updates outside of a transaction boundary. To restore 5.1 behavior, allowing flush operations outside of a transaction boundary, set **hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true**.
>
> [hibernate-orm/migration-guide.adoc at 5.2 · hibernate/hibernate-orm](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc#misc)